# Android: Why does ProgressDialog sometimes dissappear onPause(onStop)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am running AsyncTask in my application along with ProgressDialog. When I leave app (on Pause or on Stop) ProgressDialog dissappears while AsyncTask is being continued. It happens despite I set false in attribute "setCancelable" of ProgressDialog. But sometimes ProgressDialog is still alive when I return to app (like I need in this case). I can not understand what it depends on. Here is the code inside AsyncTask:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String> {


private Context mContext;
ProgressDialog mProgress;
private TaskComplete mCallback;

public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCallback = (TaskComplete) context;

}

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mProgress.setMessage("Please wait...It can take up to 3 minutes. Good luck:)");
    mProgress.show();
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}


protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... objects) {
   //do some things
}


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mProgress.dismiss();
    mCallback.onTaskComplete(result);

}
```

Comment: how do you close it before the unlikely happens

Comment: I close it the only way: I click on the mid button which brings me back to the desktop from app. But somehow I get different results. Sometimes on resume ProgressDialog is alive, sometimes is not. That's the question

Comment: Can you share your activity code? Also, does the progress dialog disappear on screen rotation?